Why does my PC FREEZE every day usually around 8am Pacific time?
Usually start before 8am and by 8:30am system has a COMPLETE freeze.
Doing a reboot clears it up for the rest of the day.
If starting system AFTER 8:am it freezes up 3 TIMES.
Thought it was the software updater since after restarting there is a update.
Did turning that off in Software Updater change anything - NO!
Was at v22 and upgraded to v24 and the freezes did not stop.
Getting SO TIRED of this!!!
Trying hard to get away from Windows which is my 2nd PC and anything that demands a gmail ID!
Is there another i386 Linux from another company that does not has this problem?
Yes different versions on Linux from different providers can bring their own problems.
Am Ubuntu Pro member.

You've provided no clues as to what Ubuntu product & release you're using; and Ubuntu Pro is from Canonical so why mention that?  This isn't a Canonical support site & doesn't provide Ubuntu Pro support.  Look for a common denominator between the OSes that have the slow down; the PC itself is one, have you ruled it out?

I don't think Ubuntu has any supported versions that can run on 386 PCs. What version are you using? Debian 12 still supports those, but supposedly that will be the last version that does.

The last release with i386 was 19.04 (not a LTS though), and the last supported release of Ubuntu that supported i386 was 18.04 which reached EOL back in May 2023. Ubuntu now only supported 32-bit ARM (armhf) as @OrganicMarble said.

Does it freeze if all internet is turned off? Or Does it freeze after 30 minutes after starting the computer?
